# Trying to access object element within an array

Tags: php, html, arrays, object

I'm using a framework at work that I'm slightly unfamiliar with and trying to access elements of an object that are stored within an array called `$items`. I've tried `die(print_r($items[0]))` to try to get the first element but it says 0 is an undefined index. Here is the result of `print_r($items)`:

Any help is much appreciated. If you have any questions I'll gladly answer because I know this is a bit vague. I think it would take up way too much space to explain how this framework actually works.

I figured out that the first element is 2 and not 0, but I'm still unable to access any of the elements within the object. When I tried `print_r($items[2]->fields)` it didn't return anything, just a blank page.

Comment: from the code it's like the key/index start at [2]. there was no zero

Comment: yeah you're right.. but I still don't know how to get any of the elements under fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
$item = current($items);
foreach ($item->fields as $key => $val) {
  echo "$key => $val\n";
}
```

**Update:**

It seems like you cannot get `$item->fields` since it is a protected property of `Dase_DBO_Project` object:

```
[fields:protected] => Array
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any element with index 0 in your array, only keys 5, 4, 3 and 2. To get the first item from array use `current($items)` or `reset($items)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your array listed here does not have an index of 0 (For more help look here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
Rather than attempting to access each item with the index. Why don't you use a `foreach`?

```
foreach($items as $item)
{
  //Do what you want with each object here
  var_dump($item);
}
```

This will allow you to access each object without using the index. For more information using `foreach` take a look here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Cheers!

Comment: Yeah I was going to use that on another page, right now I'm just trying to pull a single element from the object within the array.